# Not able to import js file or function from js file in another js file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blockchain

I've tried to import the js file in various ways and also the function in various ways and keep getting errors.

The file I am working in is called Airdrop.js.  The code is below.
There is a function called countdown() where I want to make a call to another file called issue-tokens.js that is in a directory two levels up. When the counter in the countdown() function hits zero I want to call this issue-tokens.js file or the function in it...whichever one I can get to work.  The issue-tokens.js code is below Airdrop.js at the bottom of this page for your reference. I hope what i'm asking is somewhat clear. It's odd because I can call the issue-tokens.js file no problem from the command line using truffle exec scripts/issue-tokens.js, but no luck importing it.  Thank you!

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

class Airdrop extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {time: {}, seconds: 20 };
        this.timer = 0;
        this.startTimer = this.startTimer.bind(this);
        this.countDown = this.countDown.bind(this);
    }

    startTimer() {
        if(this.timer == 0 && this.state.seconds > 0) {
            this.timer = setInterval(this.countDown, 1000)
        }
    }

    countDown() {
        // 1 . countdown one second at a time
        let seconds = this.state.seconds - 1

        this.setState({
            time: this.secondsToTime(seconds),
            seconds: seconds
        })
        // 2. stop counting when we hit zero
        if(seconds == 0) {
            clearInterval(this.timer)
            //issueTokens()
        
        }
    }

    secondsToTime(secs) {
        let hours, minutes, seconds
        hours = Math.floor(secs / (60 * 60))

        let devisor_for_minutes = secs % (60 * 60)
        minutes = Math.floor(devisor_for_minutes / 60)

        let devisor_for_seconds = devisor_for_minutes % 60
        seconds = Math.ceil(devisor_for_seconds)

        let obj = {
            'h':hours,
            'm':minutes,
            's':seconds
        }
        return obj
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let timeLeftVar = this.secondsToTime(this.state.seconds)
        this.setState({time: timeLeftVar})
    }

     airdropReleaseTokens() {
        let stakingB = this.props.stakingBalance
        if(stakingB >= '50000000000000000000') {
            this.startTimer()
        }
    //issue reward token call just added 20220217
    //issueTokens = () => {
    //    this.setState({loading: true })
     //   this.state.decentralBank.methods.issueTokens().send({from: 
 this.state.account}).on('transactionHash', (hash) => {
      //  this.setState({loading:false})
 

    }
    render() {
        this.airdropReleaseTokens()
        return (
            <div style={{color:'black'}}>{this.state.time.m}:{this.state.time.s} 
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Airdrop;
```

and this is the issue-tokens.js code:

```
const DecentralBank = artifacts.require('DecentralBank');

module.exports = async function issueRewards(callback) {
    let decentralBank = await DecentralBank.deployed()
    await decentralBank.issueTokens()
    console.log('Tokens have been issued successfully!')
    callback()
}
```

Below is a screenshot of how I have the files organized. Apparently it is an issue in react that I have my issue-tokens.js file in scripts but Airdrop.js two directories down in source/components.

[codeHierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGotE.png)

Comment: I don't see where you're importing `issue-tokens.js` file in your `Airdrop` component. Also you didn't mention what error you got when you try to import.

Comment: Hello there thanks for responding! I tried to import issue-tokens.js at the top of Airdrop.js file by adding the line: import issueTokens from '../../scripts/issue-tokens';                     This gave me the following error when I try to launch the webpage with npm start from the command line: ./src/components/Airdrop.js
Module not found: You attempted to import ../../scripts/issue-tokens which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.

Comment: Assuming I eventually get the import right, I'm not even sure the best way to call the function in the body of the code. Should I just do issueTokens() or would it be better to do something like let rewardTime = issueTokens().  Thanks again for the help!

Comment: The error message you get explains it all: the **issue-tokens.js** file is outside of allowed import paths your app enforced. So bring that file somewhere inside `src/` directory and see what you get. As for calling the exported function: you can call it the same way you call any regular function in "any" programming language, there's no specialty in it.

Comment: I tried to bring it one directory down and now I am getting a different error message. I get the following: Attempted import error: '../issue-tokens' does not contain a default export (imported as 'issueTokens'). That's odd because the file definitely has an export in it.  I start the function like this: module.exports = async function issueRewards() {

Comment: I guess the reason being you're exporting a default function as "CommonJS" module and importing it into an "ES6" module. What about you try `export default async function issueRewards(callback) { /* definition */ }`?